# Can some one identify the writing a n artist seal in these photos? (Characters identified: 雪居)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

1. [image: List item]

I have a scroll that was presented to Braidwood nuclear station in 1985 by Li Peng. Any information is greatly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 1):

乙丑 - year: 1985

秋日 - season: Autumn

雪居 - place: Xueju (snow dwelling)

克弘 - author: Kè Hóng

寫 - written (by)

> 1985 Autumn at Xueju by Kè Hóng

[克](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%8B/1339351)
[image]

弘
[image]

- The seal read: 雪居